# SQL server bulk insert rowterminator failed

Tags: sql-server

I have an csv like this :

```
"F","003","abc""X","1","50A1","name","Z5AA1A005C","70008","","A1ZZZZ17","","","","","","""X","2","50A1","name","Z5AA1A005C","70007","","A1ZZZZ17","","","","","","""X","3","50A1","name","Z5AA1A005C","70000","","A1ZZZZ17","","","","","",""
```

I need to bulk insert to tabel A
from the 2nd row

```
BULK INSERT A FROM 'c:\csvtest.csv' 
  WITH
  ( 
   FIELDTERMINATOR='","',
   ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a',
   FIRSTROW = 2,
   DATAFILETYPE = 'widenative'
  )
```

the problem is when I insert, failed insert
it show error :

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 15 The bulk load failed. The column
>   is too long in the data file for row 1, column 15. Verify that the
>   field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly. Msg 7301,
>   Level 16, State 2, Line 15 Cannot obtain the required interface
>   ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server
>   "(null)".

I have tried rowterminator : '0x0a','\n','\r\n','char(10)' but nothing works

Comment: What *is* the row terminator in your data? Have you tried `\r` as a terminator? `\n` is the default terminator for this command. `\r` is used in Linux systems

Comment: for now using '0x0a'

Comment: I don't think you can use [a hex value as a terminator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485.aspx). If the source system is Unix/Linux, you should try `\r`, not \`n`.

Comment: but \r not work either, the bulk insert failed to read rowterminator

Comment: PS: Was the edit accidental? You now show a single, very long line, whose third value contains a double quote. What *does* the file contain?

Comment: sorry, if I open the data in notepad++ it show 4 row, but in notepad it show just single line, I don't know if this the problem or not

Comment: What happens when you set the last row value to include perhaps only a few lines?  does it error out when you only import 1-2 lines?

Comment: yes, it still give error message

Answer (score 0):

Although it will only be inserting data from row2 row 1 still needs to be in the correct format as I'm pretty sure SQLServer performs a 'pre-validation' cycle against the Schema to ensure you have half a chance of the data getting to the database. Row 1 fails this 'pre-validation' because you have not provided all the columns as per the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Open the file in Notepad then check it for line structure and save it again.

Comment: this file can't be checked everytime, the app will run it automaticly, any way to check the structure and save automaticly?

Comment: I guess ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'